# PDF Automation using URL that's a continuation from what is already opened

Tags: c#, pdf, selenium, automation, pdfbox

Currently i'm using Selenium Webdriver for c# and PDFBox to automate the PDF text of a report. Now, using PDFBox, we have the ability to parse a pdf given a URL link, with URL  = new URL("link of pdf"); However, this takes the URL link directly without preconditions.

If I access the PDF with the direct URL address, I get a "resource not found" error. I essentially would need to log into the application, and select the report that I need in order to load the actual PDF. This has the same address, except it was loaded in the application instead of being loaded directly. How would I link Selenium with PDFbox?, so that instead of the code opening a new URL that goes directly to the Denied Permissions URL, it would go to the PDF Report that's already preloaded on the screen, with the same URL address?

```
         URL url = new URL("link of url");
    BufferedInputStream input = new  BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        PDFParser parsepdf = new PDFParser(input);
        parsepdf.parse();
        textofpdf = new PDFTextStripper().getText(parsepdf.getPDDocument())
```

So essentially, I have a Selenium Test class that executes the functionality of logging in, and opening the Report. After that, I make a call to the above PDFParse method. This method currently functions as if a new URL is loaded, instead of continuing with the current Selenium session.

Comment: After logging in, are you using the same browser to access the PDF URL or opening a new browser?

Comment: In the same browser, and it automatically opens in a different tab.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

try this:

```
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
    PDDocument pdDoc = null;
    COSDocument cosDoc = null;
    String parsedText = null;

        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new         InetSocketAddress("172.18.65.50", 8080));
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection(proxy);
        urlc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0a2) Gecko/20110613 Firefox/6.0a2");
       RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream file = new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(file);         
        parser.parse();
        cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
        pdfStripper.setEndPage(1);

        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
```